# why SDL_RWFromFile( file ,"w+") does not read and write like its supposed to? it only opens file for writing

Tags: c++, sdl

can someone explain to me why this  code won't work as expected. It seems SDL_RWFromFile using the w+ mode only works for writing and Not READING AND WRITING as its supposed to... what am i doing wrong

i dont want to have a different handler for reading and a different one for writing

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char* args[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    int scores=2;

    SDL_RWops* rwScore=SDL_RWFromFile("highscore.dat","w+");

    SDL_RWwrite(rwScore,&scores,sizeof(int),1);


    int fromfile=0;

    SDL_RWread(rwScore,&fromfile,sizeof(int),1);

    cout<<fromfile<<endl;



    return 0;
}
```

this prints out 0;

Comment: I'm not at computer right now, so I can't check this, but I think you should use [SDL_RWseek](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWseek) to start again from the beginning.

Comment: Yeah thanks you are right, this is the answer i was looking for. I just saw this,it would have saved me a ton of time. Thanks Lasoloz

Comment: I'm happy to hear that the problem is resolved. Also, I would suggest you to use standard C++ streams instead of SDL RW operation, since you are using C++.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in `"w+"` that means:

> write/update: Create an empty file and open it for update (both for
>   input and output). If a file with the same name already exists its
>   contents are discarded and the file is treated as a new empty file

See the description of all flags here:

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWFromFile

Comment: how do i use one handler to both read and write without creating multiple SDL_RWops structures... Thats the question im really asking. which mode would you use for that, "w+" or "r+" or what?

Comment: @3rdhope : "a+" append/update: Open a file for update (both for input and output) with all output operations writing data at the end of the file. Repositioning operations (fseek, fsetpos, rewind) affects the next input operations, but output operations move the position back to the end of file. The file is created if it does not exist.

Comment: You do not understand, i need to use SDL for that, specifically the SDL_RWFromFile function... which does or supposed to do the same thing as the fopen function and "a+" still doesnt work. Have you used SDL before?

Comment: yep iv been there before. Still no luck

Comment: the problem is that i did not use  SDL_RWseek  to start from the beginnng as Lasoloz said